# MVC3 Form NOT getting to the controller on POST (jquery.form)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitWork", "ActivitySubmission", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "activityForm", Name = "pba-activity-form-" + item.ActivityTemplateId, Id = "pba-activity-form-" + item.ActivityTemplateId })){
//Some stuff here
<input type="submit" ... />
}
```

when it get's POSTed, the code never actually reaches the controller. The form uses jquery.form (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/). The javascript:

```
    function setOptions(formData, jqForm, options){
        var parts = $(jqForm).prop("id").split("-");
        var activityTemplateId = parts[3];
        var resultsDivId = "#activityResults" + activityTemplateId;
        var msg = '<div style="height:40px; margin-right:20px; float:left;"><img src="/Content/loadingSpinner.gif" /></div>' +
            'Saving your work...<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
        $(resultsDivId).html(msg).slideDown();
    }

    $(".activityForm").ajaxForm({
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSubmit: setOptions,
        success: function (data) {
            if ($(this).valid) {
                var x = data.message;
                var y = data.status;
                var z = data.data;
            }
        }
    });
```

The setOptions function is basically just to render a "loading" div inside the form to let the user know that something is happening.

When the code runs and the submit button is clicked, everything runs normally UNTIL the actual post. The post never hits the controller (ie. in debug mode: it never breaks, the code doesn't get executed, etc) and just returns as a "success". When it returns, the variable "data" contains a string of the HTML of the entire page.

I know it's difficult to diagnose an issue like this with just what I've put down, but can anyone give me some ideas on what may be happening? I'm not getting ANY indication that there is a 404 or anything happening behind the scenes, or anything wrong at all....

The controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitWork(long activityTemplateId, long studentProjectId)
{
    //stuff

    return Json(someDataResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Have you watched the request / response cycle in your dev tools?

Comment: It looks like it's posting to itself, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. I partially expected that to be the case, but again, I have no idea why. The HTML tells it where to post to, it just seems to ignore it?